# Why is getimagesize() returning false?

Tags: php, getimagesize

I have this code on my computer and it runs perfectly fine but when someone else tries to run it in a different environment, `getimagesize()` is returning false every time for some reason (should be returning true a lot).  Any ideas why this snippet of code would run completely different in different environments?

```
$i = 2;
while ($i != 0){
    $theFile = "url/to/images/" . $image . $i . ".GIF";
    //echo $theFile . "<br />";
    if ($imageSize = @getimagesize($theFile)){
        //echo "added...<br />";
        $theRow .= "<a href='" . $theFile . "' rel='lightbox[" . $image . "]'></a>";
        $i++;
    }else{
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment out the two lines there all `$theFile`'s print to the screen fine and they are all valid URLs but it's just a bunch of

```
thisimage2.GIF
thatimage2.GIF
anotherimage2.GIF
...
```

They all end with 2.GIF but there are many that should have 3, 4, 5, 6 all the way up to 12.GIF but it's never increasing $i because it never returns true with getimagesize().   Again, when I uncomment `echo $theFile . "<br />";` it prints valid URLs to images that the other person can paste into a browser address bar and see the image just fine.

I'm running php 5.4.17 and the exact same code works fine for me.  The other machine is running php 5.4.7 and it's not working correctly.  I tried to look up any differences between the two versions for getimagesize() but couldn't find anything.

**Edit:** When run without the "@" on getimagesize() on the machine where it's not working it gives the following warning: `Warning: getimagesize(): Unable to find the wrapper “https” - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

Comment: Start by getting rid of `@` and read possible error messages?!

Comment: Where are you changing $image and $theFile?

Comment: I will do that deceze and have the person run it again.

Comment: Fred, $image is changing further up the code.  That's all working fine because when I print $theFile it's showing the changed image names.  

$theFile is changing there in the while loop.

Comment: Updated my original post with the warning it gives when we removed the "@" in front of getimagesize().

Comment: And what is not clear to you about this warning …?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong here. Fortunately, most of them are easy fixes.

1. `$image` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere, but maybe it has and you just didn't include it.
2. There's no text in between each opening and closing `<a>` tag, so the only thing you'd see would be links like this: `<a href='url/to/images/imagename1.GIF' rel='lightbox[]'></a>` (but again, maybe that's intentional).
3. `$theRow` doesn't appear to echoed anywhere, but maybe it is and you just didn't include that part. Further, it doesn't look like `$theRow` was initially defined anywhere either.
4. Your `while()` loop will only display the last image processed. In this case, I'd use a `for()` loop instead.

If your goal is to build up `$theRow` and then display it all at the end, I'd go with something like this instead:

```
<?php
// EDIT: check to see if openssl exists first, due to the https error you're receiving.
$extensions = get_loaded_extensions();
if (!in_array('openssl', $extensions)) {
   echo 'OpenSSL extension not loaded in this environment';
}
// Define $theRow first
$theRow = '';
// "Given that $i = 0, while $i is less than 3, auto-increment $i"
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
  $theFile = "url/to/images/" . $image . $i . ".GIF";
  //echo $theFile . "<br />";
  // Remove the @ sign to display errors if you want
  if ($imageSize = @getimagesize($theFile)){
    //echo "added...<br />";
    // Add to $theRow, using $theFile as the text displayed in between each <a> tag
    $theRow .= "<a href='" . $theFile . "' rel='lightbox[" . $image . "]'>" . $theFile . "</a>";
  }
  else {
    //This should only appear if $imageSize didn't work.
    echo '$imageSize has not been set for ' . $theFile . '<br />';
  }
}
// Now that $theRow has been built, echo the whole thing
echo $theRow;
```